# C# The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced

Tags: c#, ip-address, socketexception, system.net

I got this error when I tried to parse an IP address that was in string form.

I was using a public dns ip address (4.2.2.2) while testing this (using the System.Net's IPAddress.Parse method).

It does the parsing correctly and returns an IPAddress object. However, if I try to access the ScopeId property of this object, a SocketException is thrown with the message given in the title.

I really am not able to figure out whats the problem here. When I checked the documentation of IPAddress.ScopeId property, it says an exception is thrown when AddressFamily=InterNetwork which is the case with my example.

Could someone please explain the reason for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`ScopeID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.scopeid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) specific field. You have an [IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) address. Therefore, an exception is raised. *InterNetwork* in this case means IPv4.

Comment: Alright, so how do I parse an IPv4 address using this method?

Comment: Just don't query the ScopeID. `IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse( "4.2.2.2" );`

Comment: ok, the actual problem is i have used a property of type IPAddress for an entity in EntityFramework, so when I call context.SaveChanges() it is trying to query the ScopeId and hence throwing the exception.

So are you saying that a property of type IPAddress cannot be used in the entity class of EF?

Comment: Why not just store the IP address as a string? The IPAddress object doesn't give you any more data than that.