# EF, How to save/retrieve TimeSpan as other data type?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, timespan

SQLCe doesn't support TimeSpan, so I need to save this in some other way. Is it possible to define somewhere a default conversion, like in the DbContext, or would I need to handle this manually in the repositories? I don't like to change my entity classes just because of this.

Btw, I only save TimeSpan of < 24h.

Example would be great if there are some neat tricks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, it seems this is basically NOT POSSIBLE.

A `TimeSpan` property must be marked `NotMapped`, or by fluent `Ignore` (then saved as per Steve's answer).
At least that's my understanding now.

`EF` does not support type mapping or type conversion.. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12053328

Btw, `NHibernate` maps `TimeSpan` to integer by default, when using `SqLite`. No conversions or tricks needed there. Not sure about other databases.

Comment: Honestly no. My question was to get an answer on how to save a TimeSpan without changing the entity class. You neither confirmed if that was impossible, nor why it is impossible, which I consider an accepted answer should include. I would not go for your solution until I knew this information, and in fact I ditched EF in favor of NHibernate because type conversions are not possible in EF. It can't even save enum as string, which I need.

Comment: ..above comment was a reply to this, which was deleted; http://i.imgur.com/8QfpLqG.png

Comment: I removed it because you were correct. Thanks for the downvote I assume accompanied that too.

Comment: Not proper etiquette to just silently remove a comment like that after it's replied to. If I hadn't checked back my comment would been left as an oddity.  And without my downvote you would not have checked back to see what you'd accomplished ;)

Comment: I'm still not sure what I accomplished, and I'm still not sure it was improper to remove it.

Comment: SQL do save TimeSpan <24h. The equivalent is [time(0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb677243.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

I know you say you don't want to modify your entities, but if you're using code first this would be pretty simple to do by modifying your entities :)

You could define a property that isn't mapped into the database, that uses another property as its backing store. In this example, TickCount would get saved in the database, but everything else could access Span which exposes TickCount as a TimeSpan struct.

```
public long TickCount { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public TimeSpan Span { 
    get { 
        return new TimeSpan(TickCount); 
    } 
    set { 
        TickCount = value.Ticks; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yea that fine. I'm just trying to understand if it's at all possible to map it without touching the class. Trying to set DbModelBuilder.Entity<>().Property(...).HasColumnType  seems not to make any difference. Can't avoid exception. So am I FORCED to assign .Ignore/NotMapped on all TimeSpan properties?

Comment: Don't know. I've never actually stored a TimeSpan. I've used this technique for serializing a Dictionary<> into a string column though.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old but in case anyone ever needs this, I have cloned and modified System.Data.SQLite in order to support TimeSpan properties (mapped to sqlite TIME columns)
You can find the source at https://github.com/arielflashner/System.Data.SQLite