# How to best map a string array from a legacy database to EF5 property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

We need to map a string column from a database, that is used as an array of values, to a list of business entities in Entity Framework 5.

In the database the information is stored as a string of length 12, where each character in the string defines whether something is enabled/disabled. A value of 0 for the character means the item is disabled, a value of 1 for the character means the is enabled.

For example if the first and second items are to be enabled and the rest disabled the value in the db would be 110000000000.

In the business entities we want these configurations to be represented as a list so that manipulation and binding to the presentation layer would be easier, ideally this would be represented by a list of objects containing the index value and a boolean to define whether it is active or not.

Normalizing the database is sadly not an option, it is in active use by other applications.

We could perhaps create a view in the database and map to that, or as an additional property in the entity marked as "not mapped to the database" that would make the transformation but each has its limitations.

And of course this happens in more than one place so if we can define a pattern for this case we can reuse it all the way throughout the project and save some hair.

Any suggestions on a good way to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at this answer that I wrote that shows how to perform a conversion automatically from the database to object and back: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18473180/425871 I've used this to store a `Dictionary<K,V>` into a string column. You can do any conversion you want from simply to really fancy-complicated if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I will discuss with my colleagues and try a few things out to see what works best in our project.

Comment: Steve, that is exactly what we ended up doing. Not sure at this point if I should answer my own question or give you the opportunity to put the answer in and I can accept that.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this with the [Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx)

Something like this is what I am imagining you needing.

```
[ComplexType]
public class MagicString
{
    public string key { get; set; }    
    public <IList> YourMagicalList { get; set; }
}
public class Context : DbContext
{    
    public DbSet<SomeConfigurationObject> ConfigurationObjects { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {       
        modelBuilder.Entity<SomeConfigurationObject>().Property(u => u.MagicString.key)
                                   .HasColumnName(""YourColumn");


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just [map this flag column to corresponding flag entity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/06/29/enumeration-support-in-entity-framework.aspx) object without changing any data, Entity framework supports flags since version 4 I believe.

```
    [Flags]
    public enum FlagObject : byte
    {
        One = 1,
        Two = 2,
        Three = 4,
        Four = 8,
        Five = 16,
        Six = 32,
        Seven = 64,
        Eight = 128,
        Nine = 256,
        Ten = 512,
        Eleven = 1024,
        Twelve = 2048,
    }
```

When declaring in Flags in EDM specify as a flag:

```
<EnumType Name="FlagObject" IsFlags="true">
  <Member Name="One" Value="1"/>
  <Member Name="Two" Value="2"/>
...
</EnumType>
```